# JQUERY - Set value after load dropdown

Tags: jquery

I have this function:

```
function loadlist(selobj,url,id_nameattr, nameattr, message){
    $(selobj).empty();
    $.getJSON(url,{},function(data)
    {

        $(selobj).append('<option value="" selected disabled>'+message+'</option>');
        $.each(data, function(i,obj)
        {
            $(selobj).append(
                 $('<option></option>')
                        .val(obj[id_nameattr])
                        .html(obj[nameattr]));
        });
    });

}
```

I would like to after load a dropdown:

```
loadlist("#myselect", url, "id", "name", "Selecte a value");
```

Set a value:

```
$.("#myselect").val(1);
```

I was trying:

```
$.when(loadlist("#myselect", url, "id", "name", "Selecte a value")).done(function(){  $.("#myselect").val(1); });
```

Won't work.

Could you please give me an idea?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument to `$.when()` should be a `Deferred`, but `loadlist` doesn't return anything. It should return what `$.getJSON` returns:

```
function loadlist(selobj,url,id_nameattr, nameattr, message){
    $(selobj).empty();
    return $.getJSON(url,{},function(data)
    {

        $(selobj).append('<option value="" selected disabled>'+message+'</option>');
        $.each(data, function(i,obj)
        {
            $(selobj).append(
                 $('<option></option>')
                        .val(obj[id_nameattr])
                        .html(obj[nameattr]));
        });
    });

}
```